# Is there any difference between never and void return type in swift? what is the use of never return type in practically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there any difference between never and void return type in swift?

For example:

```
   func display() -> Never {
       //code here
   }
```

What will be the difference if I kept the return type as Void like this?

```
   func display() -> Void {
        //code here
   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46902700/1271826

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Never return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902700/what-is-the-never-return-type)

Comment: Also possibly helpful: [When and how to use @noreturn attribute in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38098802/1187415).

Comment: Do not replace the question with an unrelated question. If you have a new question ask it as a new question by clicking the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Void**

A return type that doesn’t return a value.

**Never**

Something that will never return.

**Void vs Never**

- Implementation: Void is a tuple, Never is an empty enum.
- Never informs the compiler that there is no need to return a value.
- Never is used in methods that will unconditionally throw an error or crash the system.